# Obtaining a cell value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to obtain an exact value from my dataframe, it means I'm interested in in just one from all my dataframe.

Now I'm doing this,

```
val = df['Pols'][(df['DevId'] == devid) & (df['Fosqui'] == i)].values[0]
```

Where `DevId` is the identifier from my device, `Fosqui` is another project identifier and `Pols` is the column that has the value what I want to obtain.

I feel I'm doing very hard to something that has to be easy? How you do this?

NOTE: I don't want a dataframe of one row, I want the value.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

Try via `loc`:

```
val = df.loc[((df['DevId'] == devid) & (df['Fosqui'] == i)),'Pols'].values[0]
```